# sql statement to alphabetize and count

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Here is the mySQL I got

```
id   terms    
1    a       
2    c       
3    a       
4    b       
5    b       
6    a       
7    a
8    b
9    b
10   b
```

I want to get an alphabetized list sorted by count as follows

```
terms  count
a      4
b      5
c      1
```

What mySQL statement do I need for that?

Comment: a `group by` clause, a `count` aggregate function, and an `order by` clause.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe something like this will work:

```
SELECT terms, COUNT( id) AS count 
    FROM table 
GROUP BY terms 
ORDER BY terms DESC
```

Comment: how do you create a table with that so that the results are in the mysql table, instead of on the screen?

Comment: Like a temporary table? You can [do this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0080__Table/Usingaquerytocreatethetemporarytable.htm). But the temporary table won't be dynamic - That is, it won't reflect any changes that are made to the original table.

Comment: Nick thank you. Please answer that here ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325352/sql-statement-to-create-a-table-as-a-result-of-a-count-operation ) cause I made that a separate question.

Answer (score 6):

Read : [GROUP BY (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

Groups a selected set of rows into a set of summary rows by the values of one or more columns or expressions in SQL. One row is returned for each group. Aggregate functions in the SELECT clause  list provide information about each group instead of individual rows.

You just need to apply `group by` clause for getting result

```
select terms, count (id) as count from table 
group by terms 
order by terms
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar need for a used record store to display artists in stock alphabetically with their count in parenthesis e.g.:

Smokey Robinson and The Miracles (2) | Sonic Youth (2) | Spoon (3) | Steely Dan (1) | Stevie Wonder (2) | Sufjan Stevens (1) |

Note that I used SELECT DISTINCT when pulling from my table "records".  Here are the relevant code snippets:

```
//QUERY
$arttool = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM records GROUP BY artist ORDER BY artist ASC");

//OUTPUT LOOP START
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($arttool)){

//CAPTURE ARTIST IN CURRENT LOOP POSITION
$current=$row['Artist'];    

//CAPTURING THE NUMBER OF ALBUMS IN STOCK BY CURRENT ARTIST
$artcount = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM records WHERE artist = '$current'"));

//ECHO OUT. 
echo $current . "($artcount)";
```

The actual code in my site is more complicated, but this is the bare bones of it.  Hope that helps...