# SQL Statement to create a table as a result of a count operation?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, recordset

Let's say you got a table like this

```
id   terms    
1    a       
2    c       
3    a       
4    b       
5    b       
6    a       
7    a
8    b
9    b
10   b
```

and you want to end up with a report like this;

```
terms  count
a      4
b      5
c      1
```

So you run this over the first table

```
SELECT terms, COUNT( id) AS count 
    FROM table 
GROUP BY terms 
ORDER BY terms DESC
```

So far so good.

But the above SQL statment puts the report view on the browser. Well, I want to save that data into a SQL.

So, what SQL command do I need to insert the results of that report into a table?

Assume that you already created a table called `reports` with this;

```
create table reports (terms varchar(500), count (int))
```

Let's assume that the `reports` table is empty and we just want to populate it with the following view - with a one-liner. The question I'm asking is how?

```
  terms  count
    a      4
    b      5
    c      1
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As simple as that:

```
INSERT INTO reports
SELECT terms, COUNT( id) AS count 
FROM table 
GROUP BY terms 
ORDER BY terms DESC
```

Comment: I cringe at the thought of pushing data into a table in a specific order.  Mostly because you aren't guaranteed to get the data _out_ in that order 'by default' - it requires an `ORDER BY` statement on the selection end.

Answer (score 1):

if the table exists already:

```
Insert reports
SELECT terms, COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM table 
GROUP BY terms
```

if not:

```
SELECT terms, COUNT(*) AS count 
into reports
FROM table 
GROUP BY terms
```